# Making a char** with std::?

Tags: c++

I have an opengl function that requires a const char**. So essentially a vector of strings. I was wondering if this could be done using the C++ Standard Library without making a vector of `const char*` which would demand heap allocation.

Comment: The title says `char **` but the body says `const char*` and gets more confusing from there (why are you trying to avoid heap allocation?). Please clarify, preferably with code.

Comment: I need to read strings from a file and I want to add and remove strings with ease.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're wanting to avoid heap allocation:

```
const char* arrayOfStrings[] = {
    "first string",
    "second string",
    "third string"
};
```

And you can use `arrayOfStrings` as a `const char**`.

If you have a vector of `const char*`s you can just get the address of the first element to obtain a `const char**`:

```
&vec[0];
```

However, what do you mean when you say "using [c++ standard library]"? You say you want to "use the [C++ standard libary] without making a vector of `const char*`". That doesn't make much sense.

You don't need the standard library for this, please clarify your question if my answer isn't sufficient.

Comment: <troll>And, presumably he's referring to the C++ Standard Library, not the STL.</troll>

Comment: @Tomalak I don't get your <troll>

Comment: @Seth: [The STL is *not* the C++ Standard Library.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205491/whats-this-stl-vs-c-standard-library-fight-all-about/5205571#5205571)

Comment: @Tomalak Obviously, and no one here thinks it is, but why was your comment enclosed in <troll> tags

Comment: @Seth: Many people think that it is. You yourself referred to it in your answer, despite the fact that pretty much nobody uses the STL any more, and `std::` certainly has nothing to do with it. However, this discussion often becomes a heated debate, which is why I decided in advance to declare a slight tongue-in-cheek approach to my original comment (in an attempt to avoid a debate, whilst still satisfying my OCD urges to make the correction :P).

Comment: @Tomalak Ohhhhhhh, I see what you mean. In that case, I was mistaken as I thought STL was a synonym for the thing that contains `vector` and all those headers and stuff. I'll _attempt_ to fix my answer. Thanks, I had not known that before.

Comment: @Seth: Disclaimer: Not everybody agrees with my viewpoint. As much as I wish I could claim 100% authority, "mistaken" might be a little strong a word here. (And, FWIW, the STL _does_ have a `vector`... but it does not have `std::vector` - which comes with your toolchain.)

Comment: @Tomalak I know this is unrelated but I don't know where else to ask. I read this sentence in your profile thing: `and there's no such thing as "heap" or "stack" in the context in which you're trying to use it`. I _think_ I know what the stack and heap (free store) are, but that sentence makes me less confident, considering what I just learned about the STL. So what does that sentence in your profile mean?

Comment: @Seth: When people say "stack" or "heap", they usually mean "automatic storage duration" or "dynamic storage duration" respectively. Oftentimes a heap structure (as you say, "free store" is better) is not even involved, and "stack objects" if members of a dynamically allocated object are not on your callstack.